# ip link add test_team_slave type team_slave - RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, bonding, kernel-modules, network-teaming

Trying to set up teaming on a Crux Linux with a custom kernel. I have teamd and teamdctl already installed on my system, I managed to find kernel modules for teaming and successfully enabled them. Tested it by running `ip link add testTeam type team`, which was failing before rebuilding the kernel. Right now I have issues with the team_slave type, and I can't find which module I am missing. I would appreciate any help!

For the context, here is nmtui configuration of the team I've created. When I try to activate it, I get this message: `Could not activate connection: Activation failed: The base network connection was interrupted`

[image: team1 config in nmtui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that dbus was logging errors like this one:

```
dbus: Failed to acquire org.libteam.teamd.team1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.831" is not allowed to own the service "org.libteam.teamd.team1" due to security policies in the configuration file
```

So after I added this [configuration](https://github.com/jpirko/libteam/blob/master/teamd/dbus/teamd.conf) to the **/etc/dbus-1/system.d** directory, error messages from NetworkManager and dbus disappeared and NetworkManager was able to create teaming.